# XML SQL find and replace

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 db column, we will call XMLDoc, that contains XML in the following format:

```
<XMLDoc xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.xxx.xxx.xxx">
  <Node>
    <SubNode>
      <SubSubNode>Value, Value, Value</SubSubNode>
      <IrrelevantNode></IrrelevantNode>
    </SubNode>
    ...
```

The `SubSubNode` houses anywhere from 0 to 20+ values separated by commas. Single values should not contain commas, but they were incorrectly entered with them. For example, the following `SubSubNode` would be correct:

`<SubSubNode>Value, Value, Value</SubSubNode>`

The following `SubSubNode` is incorrect:

`<SubSubNode>Value, </SubSubNode>`

I need to find and replace all instances of single values with commas to appear as:

`<SubSubNode>Value</SubSubNode>`

Since SQL does not allow `ends-with`, `starts-with`, or `matches`, I've only been able to come up with the following (This is only searching for the values, I haven't worked on the replace yet):

```
with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://schemas.xxx.xxx.xxx')
select [XMLDoc].value('(/XMLDoc/Node/SubNode/SubSubNode)[1]','varchar(2000)')
from XMLDoc 
where [XMLDoc].exist('/XMLDoc/Node/SubNode[1] [contains(SubSubNode[1],", ")]')=1
```

Obviously this selects all values with a comma, and not only the single values with a comma.

Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using your parsing above to build some sort of derived column containing the data from your SubNode Element and then using sql based parsing functions to find where the trailing value is a comma?

I just used a couple of different xml docs to show what I mean...you could build a variation of this to find the rows that match this pattern....not an xquery technique for finding the pattern, but should work.

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<XMLDoc xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.xxx.xxx.xxx">
     <Node>
    <SubNode>
      <SubSubNode>Value, Value,</SubSubNode>
      <IrrelevantNode></IrrelevantNode>
    </SubNode>
   </Node>
  </XMLDoc>'

 DECLARE @XML2 XML = '<XMLDoc xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.xxx.xxx.xxx">
     <Node>
    <SubNode>
      <SubSubNode>Value</SubSubNode>
      <IrrelevantNode></IrrelevantNode>
    </SubNode>
   </Node>
  </XMLDoc>'

DECLARE @xmlTbl TABLE(XmlDoc VARCHAR(MAX))


;with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://schemas.xxx.xxx.xxx')
 Insert Into @xmlTbl
select @XML.value('(/XMLDoc/Node/SubNode/SubSubNode)[1]','varchar(2000)');

;with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://schemas.xxx.xxx.xxx')
 Insert Into @xmlTbl
select @XML2.value('(/XMLDoc/Node/SubNode/SubSubNode)[1]','varchar(2000)')

Select *
From @xmlTbl
Where RIGHT(XmlDoc,1) = ','
```